# Is it possible to find a channel that the bot have permission to type?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to let the bot auto find a channel where it can send messages, but it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```js
const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(c => 
  c.type === 'text' && 
  c.me.hasPermission('SEND_MESSAGES')
)
```

Comment: What's your discord.js version?

Comment: the version is 12.5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `c` is a [`GuildChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v12/class/GuildChannel) and it doesn't have a `me` property.

If you want to check if your bot has permission to send messages in a channel, you can use the [`channel#permissionsFor()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v12/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=permissionsFor) method. It accepts a `GuildMemberResolvable` or a `RoleResolvable` and returns [`Permissions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v12/class/Permissions). The returned value has a `has()` method that you can use to check if the permissions include the `SEND_MESSAGES` flag.

You can use `guild.me` as a `GuildMemberResolvable` for the `permissionsFor()` method. [`guild.me`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v12/class/Guild?scrollTo=me) returns the bot as a `GuildMember` of this guild.

So, to find the first text channel where the bot can send a message, your code should look something like this:

```js
// discord.js v12
const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(
  (ch) =>
    ch.type === 'text' &&
    ch.permissionsFor(guild.me).has('SEND_MESSAGES')
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your **hasPermission** function is outdated with discord.js v13, you have now to use:

```
c.me.permissions.has("SEND_MESSAGES")
```

More informations here: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#channel-overwrites

Comment: but my discord.js version is 12.5.3

Comment: And even in v13 it will just throw an error.